# Canvas Apps: signed_request POST parameter is named different

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-canvas

I have the feeling that some documentation is out of date?

for example look [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/).

It says: `$signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];`

but when I print the request I get: `[fbsr_(my_app_id)] => (long_string)`

I assume that this is the actual `signed_request`, am I right???

Answer (score 0):

Some of the documentation on Facebook is [automatically](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/06/making-our-documentation-better/) generated.

The `parse_signed_request` function decodes the signed request to an array of useful information.

Have you tried using `parse_signed_request` function on `$_REQUEST['signed_request']` ?